# SQLAlchemy Return All Distinct Column Values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am creating a website using Flask and SQLAlchemy.  This website keeps track of classes that a student has taken.  I would like to find a way to search my database using SQLAlchemy to find all unique classes that have been entered.  Here is code from my `models.py` for Class:

```
class Class(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'classes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user_email = db.Column(db.String(100), db.ForeignKey(User.email))
    user = db.relationship(User)
```

In other words, I would like to get all unique values from the title column and pass that to my `views.py`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
query = session.query(Class.title.distinct().label("title"))
titles = [row.title for row in query.all()]
```

Comment: Why would anyone know this? Can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @AlxVallejo: yes, you can find it in the documentation. Use search functionality for this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/search.html?q=distinct

Comment: @van what is the syntax with `select(Class...` instead of `session.query(..`?

Comment: Hi @Riya, this should produce the same result: `query = select(Class.title.distinct().label("title"))`

Answer (score 35):

Using the model query structure you could do this

```
Class.query.with_entities(Class.title).distinct()
```

Comment: I think this answer is important as OP is probably using Flask-Sqlalchemy and might want to stay closer to the syntax found in most Flask tutorials.

Answer (score 7):

```
titles = [r.title for r in session.query(Class.title).distinct()]
```

Answer (score 4):

As @van has pointed out, what you are looking for is:

```
session.query(your_table.column1.distinct()).all(); #SELECT DISTINCT(column1) FROM your_table
```

but I will add that in most cases, you are also looking to add another filter on the results. In which case you can do

```
session.query(your_table.column1.distinct()).filter_by(column2 = 'some_column2_value').all();
```

which translates to sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column1) FROM your_table WHERE column2 = 'some_column2_value';
```