# **SQLAlchemy**:Get a count of one column where another column is distinct

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sqlalchemy

This is killing me! I'm sure it's a gap in my SQL knowledge, but I'm having massive trouble solving this issue.
I need to get a count of all orders for each country. The catch is the orders need to have a unique user_id in order to include only unique customers in the count.
Here's what I have presently, it returns a total count including orders from the same user_id.

```
country_col = model.Order.__table__.c.shipping_country_code
country_q = model.Session.query(country_col,
                                    func.count('*'))\
        join(model.Order.cart).\
        join(model.Cart.items).\
        join(model.CartItem.product).\
        filter(model.Product.project_id == project.id).\
        group_by(country_col).\
        order_by(func.count('*').desc())

country_q.all()
```

I'm sorry if this seems to be a duplicate. I've read all of the StackOverflow questions and their comments/answers, but I can't translate the solutions to my problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close - essentially you will need to tell your query what to count

```
country_col = model.Order.__table__.c.shipping_country_code
country_q = model.Session.query(country_col,
                                #here's where you need to indicate the value
                                func.count(order_id.distinct()))\
    join(model.Order.cart).\
    join(model.Cart.items).\
    join(model.CartItem.product).\
    filter(model.Product.project_id == project.id).\
    group_by(country_col).\
    order_by(func.count(order_id.distinct()).desc())

country_q.all()
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275619/7853322

Comment: Wow wow wow! Thank you so much! I had to add the user_id to the query          

```country_q = model.Session.query(country_col, model.Order.user_id,
                                func.count(order_id.distinct()))\```                 

But then it worked perfectly! Thank you so much, you're a life saver!